# Login loop for FreeIPA users

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, freeipa

I am running into an issue with one of my newly configured freeipa clients where all of the ipa users that try to log into the computer go through a login loop. New users, and users with their passwords reset, can change their passwords but are sent right back to the login screen after authenticating. I have four freeipa clients, all of which are running Ubuntu 20.04.3. The three that work just fine are hand-built systems, and the client that doesn't work is a Dell. I can SSH into the Dell client using ipa credentials though.

My freeipa server is on a VM running CentOS 7, and the home directories for the ipa users are on an NFS server running Ubuntu 20.04.3.

I have tried looking at Xauthority and /tmp file permissions, but the Xauthority file doesn't exist in the ipa user's home directory, and the permissions of /tmp look okay from what I can see. I've never implemented LDAP authentication before, but since the issue is isolated to just one client, it makes me think this is a client-side issue rather than an LDAP one.

Comment: Is selinux enabled on the new client? If yes - is `use_nfs_home_dirs` set to `on`?

Comment: I don't think so. sestatus isn't a found command on the client.

Comment: so what's in the log files? You may consider simplifyiing the setup to rule out things first, so no nfs mounts, local homedirs. Does it work? Then try nfs, and so on

Comment: which log files should I check? should I start on my ldap server or the local client?

Comment: You are having a client issue. I suppose ubuntu uses sssd too, so this would be a good place https://sssd.io/troubleshooting/basics.html